# PHP переписка

Tags: php, mysql

Многоуважаемые программисты, подскажите пожалуйста, как организовать переписку средствами PHP и MySQL(Желательно), чтобы особо не "Насиловать" базу данных и не захламлять её большим количеством сообщений. Так как планируется большой объём переписок на подобие ICQ.
Меня интерисует больше алгоритм действий, нежели сам код. Но если и им поможете(к примеру, у Вас есть линк или есть готовый пример данной мысли.)
**Зарание спасибо.**

Comment: [Если правильно ввести вопрос в строку поиска, то ...][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/22314/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> если один пользователь удалить
> сообщение у себя, то и у получателя
> оно тоже получается удалится...

А смысл? а вдруг там что-то важное для того или иного участника переписки?

TABLE MESSAGES

- `id = some id`
- `sender = some id`
- `addressee = some id`
- `theme = some theme`
- `message = some message`
- `time = some time`
- `sender_status = 1` // единичка значит
     что отправитель видит сообщение у
     себя в отпраленных, соответственно 0
     нет
- `addressee_status = 1` // аналогично,
     только получатель видит у себя
     сообщение во входящих

Если отправитель нажал удалить сообщение, сверяем статус получателя сообщения, если 1 то меняем статус отправителя на 0. Если статус 0 значит удаляем сообщение полностью!

Аналогично если получатель захотел удалить сообщение, сверяем статус 1 или 0, выполняем действия

З.Ы. Если переживать о размере БД, то даже не СтОит все это затевать!

Comment: да я не за размер переживаю, 8 гигов на сервере, думаю хватит)
Я переживаю за работоспособность и скорость работы.

Comment: Ну дык все зависит от железа, если оно не мертвое то экономить на спичках нет смысла...

Answer (score 1):

Общий принцип.

На маленьких задачах - пишем в БД и не паримся.
Если это не чат, а private messsages - тоже конечно.

Иначе
Пишем в память tmpfs или memcached.
Если в течении 15-30 секунд не забрали - пишем в фиксированную область ФС.

Если нужны логи - то пишем в БД, а читаем из памяти.

Нюансы есть с неожиданным выключением.
Естественно данные в памяти в таком случае мрут.

Как вариант, можно попробовать писать на диск в файлы и не насиловать БД.
В любом случае будет пишущая транзакция на диск, что скрипта, что БД.
Есть вариант, что на файлах будет быстрее, но нужно тестироват.

Понятно, что это для нагруженных сервисов.

Comment: Вот спасибо, дорогой человек. Именно такого ответа я и ожидал) спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Для таких вещей была специально создана JS-технология - [AJAX](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax) (асинхронный JavaScript). AJAX нужен для динамических обращений к серверу за информацией, которая, собственно, на этом сервере и лежит.

Comment: Про него я знаю. Мне нужно совсем другое. Мне нужен алгоритм осуществления переписки на сайте (Как именно хранить их в БД, чтобы серв не напрягать и прочее)
Самим аяксом естественно подгружать контент удобнее, Вы наверно предложили его из-за того что я писал про "ICQ", но его я указал, лишь намекнув, о том что переписки будут частыми и БД просто лопнет от большого количества записей, меня интересует как этого избежать

Comment: Не лопнет БД =) Для того и создано множество всяких технологий, чтобы сервер не падал. Далеко за примерами ходить не надо, соц.сети кругом.

Comment: Это то понятно, а ты не мог бы подсказать как лучше это организовать? По примеру создавать строку записи в БД(тема, получатель, отправитель, текст, время), чтобы при огромном количестве сообщений не приходилось постоянно напрягать БД и принцип удаления, если один пользователь удалить сообщение у себя, то и у получателя оно тоже получается удалится...

Comment: Можете использовать XML-формат или простые HTML-файлы...